# How can I sync Outlook with my iPad?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, ms-office

I have a Outlook synced with my HTC Hero, but now I also want to sync it with my new iPad.

However, I never touched an Apple product before, so I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

So can anyone explain me where these settings are hidden?

Answer (score 1):

Use iTunes to Sync Your iPad With Your Outlook Calendar.

- Update iTunes in the computer to the recent version: click "Help" --> "Check for Updates."
- Use the cable which comes with your iPad to connect it directly to new computer.
- iTunes will launch in the PC automatically.
- In the iTunes source list, select your ipad and click on "Info" tab -> the "Sync Outlook calendars" option.
- In the lower right-hand corner of your screen, you can find the "Apply" button. Click it on.
- Then your computer will sync with your iPad.

Comment: Thanks that worked, that's what I get for trying to work around iTunes...

Answer (score 0):

If you want it synced OTA, then you can sync outlook to a gmail account (both messages and calendar), then sync your iPad with the same gmail account. This has the advantage that things that show up in outlook show up pretty quickly on your iPad (not instantly - the gmail to outlook sync isn't instantaneous) without having to plug the iPad in.

Comment: Does this also sync contacts and calendar?

Comment: Yes. I do this with my iPhone - outlook contacts and calendar sync up to gmail and then down to the phone. I actually said messages, but I haven't done that myself, and I should note that I might be wrong on that - you might have to grab mail directly from wherever it comes from (the iOS mail clients can connect to pretty much any kind of mail server directly).